# How to make a sticky menu transition smooth

Tags: jquery, css, menu, sticky

I created a sticky menu, it works perfectly, but the transition is not smooth, how do i make it?

My knowledge in jquery is very limited, so sorry if it's something very simple and I do not know.

I believe it's with .animate(), but I do not know how to apply it in my code.

```
function stick() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 140){  
    $('.header').addClass("sticky");
    $('.logo').addClass("sticky");
    $('.header-menu').addClass("sticky");
    $('.dropdown-content').addClass("sticky");
    $('#mobile-clicker').addClass("sticky");
    $('.hamburguer-img').addClass("sticky");
    $('.active').addClass("sticky");
    $('.active-drop').addClass("sticky");
    $('#searchform').addClass("sticky");
    $('.search-formulario').addClass("sticky");
} else {
    $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.logo').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.header-menu').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.dropdown-content').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#mobile-clicker').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.hamburguer-img').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.active').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.active-drop').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#searchform').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.search-formulario').removeClass("sticky");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use native javascript instead of jquery.
And for animations/transitions, I suggest CSS instead of javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp